# Where would If my goal was to do OCR pdf text extraction on 1000s of PDFs I have?

Tags: training, ai-design, optical-character-recognition

So I have lots of data (pdfs) that I want to train an AI model to extract info from. All of them are a little different but have the same key data points. Is it possible to train an AI on the pdfs I have and see if it would be able to recognize other pdfs I throw at it?

Does anyone know the best way to go about this? Sorry if this is a noob question wasn't sure where to post. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few models on [Hugging Face](https://huggingface.co) you might want to look at. [TrOCR](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/trocr) is a [transformer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformer_(machine_learning_model))-based OCR model. If you know Python, you can experiment with this and see if the current generation of technology produces better OCR results than older AI solutions like [Tesseract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract_(software)).

However, it sounds like your problem isn't OCR, it's [Document Question Answering](https://huggingface.co/models?pipeline_tag=document-question-answering). Hugging Face have a bunch of different models for this, and one of the most downloaded is [LayoutLM](https://huggingface.co/impira/layoutlm-document-qa). The "getting started" Python code demonstrates how you could use this model to ask questions expressed in natural language about a document provided in image format:

```
from transformers import pipeline

nlp = pipeline(
    "document-question-answering",
    model="impira/layoutlm-document-qa",
)

nlp(
    "https://templates.invoicehome.com/invoice-template-us-neat-750px.png",
    "What is the invoice number?"
)
# {'score': 0.9943977, 'answer': 'us-001', 'start': 15, 'end': 15}

nlp(
    "https://miro.medium.com/max/787/1*iECQRIiOGTmEFLdWkVIH2g.jpeg",
    "What is the purchase amount?"
)
# {'score': 0.9912159, 'answer': '$1,000,000,000', 'start': 97, 'end': 97}
```

Searching for tutorials on document question answering, and looking at the other [tasks and models in the Natural Language Processing category on Hugging Face](https://huggingface.co/models), will help you to explore these ideas further.